# What does "ERROR interpreting JPEG image file( invalid JPEG file structure :SOS before SOF)" mean?

Tags: c, jpeg, cs50

I am trying to recover JPG's from a .raw file, when I try and open the ".jpg's" from the out put of my program, it gives that error, or it says some weird hexadecimal and says that it is an unsupported marker type for a JPEG (But it says it is a jpg!). What am I doing wrong?

```
     *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1

#define BLOCK 512
#define START1END 0xe0
#define START2END 0xe1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


//sets the begins or jpgs
uint8_t checkjpg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
uint8_t checkjpg2[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

//making variables
int found = 0; 
char title[BLOCK];
FILE* img;
int ifopen = 1;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //opening file
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    //checking if file opening failed
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    //making buffer
    unsigned char buffer[BLOCK];

    //going through the file
    while(fread(&buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,inptr) == BLOCK)
    {
         //checking if begin == the possible begin of jpg    
         if ((buffer[0] == checkjpg1[0] && buffer[1] == checkjpg1[1] && buffer[2] == checkjpg1[2]) && 
         (buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3] || buffer[3] == checkjpg2[3]))
         {
            //if a jpg is not open
            if (ifopen == 1)
            {
                //make one
                found+=1;
                sprintf(title,"00%d.jpg",found);
                img = fopen(title,"a");
                if(buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3])
                {
                    fwrite(&checkjpg1,sizeof(char),4,img);
                }

            }
            else//else
            {
                //end the one and open new one
                fclose(img);
                found +=1;
                sprintf(title,"00%d.jpg",found);
                img = fopen(title,"a");
                if(buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3])
                {
                    fwrite(&checkjpg2,sizeof(char),4,img);
                }
            }
         }
         else if (img != NULL)
         {
            fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,img);
         }
     }

    fclose(inptr);
}
```

Comment: It just says that the file is not actually a JPEG file.  The Start-of-Scan can of course not appear before the Start-of-Frame.  And the shoe fits, a .raw file is never a jpeg file, it uses a vendor-specific format and contains uncompressed data.  You need another library, something like libraw.

Comment: Thanks, but why is my program failing then. If it is saying it is not a JPEG file, then good. I want to take the JPG's off the .raw. Why isn't it working though? I wrote the appropriate beginnings of the JPG's into the current img. I just don't understand why it isn't recognizing that it is a JPG.

Comment: What happens if `img = fopen(title,"a");` fails?

Comment: Would I check if it equals NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Start of Frame (SOF) market defines the structure of the image. A start of scan marker contains compressed image data. You need to know the size of the image (SOF) in order to expand the compressed data (SOS).

It sounds like your streams are missing the SOF marker.